# document.referrer returns empty string for page visited via hyperlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a "Back" button/link to my web page header if the user has visited multiple pages or say there is browser history.

Trying the below code:

```
window.location.pathname !== '/' && document.referrer ? 
    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
        <button type="button">
            Back
        </button>
    </a> : null
```

Now problem with above code is that if I visit a page via hyperlink, document.referrer returns an empty string there and "Back" button is not visible.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It looks like you're mixing javascript and html?

Comment: @Aaron : I am using JSX in a react project Aaron.

Comment: Sorry I can't help. Maybe split it into multiple lines and add some parenthesis.